# Visual studio Community 2017を利用してOpenPoseを動かしたい

Tags: visual-studio

お世話になります。

Visual studio Community 2017を利用してOpenPoseをインストールしようとしたところ、
`LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\x64\Release\OpenPose.lib' OpenPoseDemo`
というエラーが出ました。

そこで下記のページを参考にしたところ、上記のようなエラーが出るのはリンカによるものであるということがわかりました。
[Problem installing openpose on windows 10 using visual studio 17](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/issues/211)

しかし，対処方法について記載されている部分（上記リンク先のuvas94さんが12 Nov 2017にコメントしている箇所）を読んでみると

> """ uvas94 commented on 12 Nov 2017 """
>   ・・・I looked in the .vcxproj and change the necessary paths from Cuda 8 to Cuda 9 and found out that it works as intended without any other change.

とあります。
しかし，これを読んでみても具体的に何をしたら良いのかがイマイチ分かりません。
Pathを変更するというのは分かりますが、`OpenPose .vcxproj`をテキストエディタで開いて，`CUDA_PATH_V8_0`のところを`CUDA_PATH_V9_1`に変更してみましたが同じく`LNK1181 cannot open input file '..\x64\Release\OpenPose.lib' OpenPoseDemo`と出力されます。

何の`.vcxproj`ファイルをどのように変更するのかを教えていただきたく思います。
（もし初歩的な話でしたら大変申し訳無いです・・）

ちなみに構成は
・Visual studio Community 2017
・CUDA　v9.1
・cuDNN version:5.1（GitHubのバッチファイルをそのまま起動してインストールした）
・Caffe version: Default from OpenPose（GitHubのバッチファイルをそのまま起動してインストールした）

余談ですが、次のリンク先ではVisual studio 2015を推奨しています。しかしVisual studio Community 2015をインストールしてReleaseでビルドすると`MSB8020 The build tools for v141 (Platform Toolset = 'v141') cannot be found.`と出てくるので断念しました。
[OpenPose - Installation](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/installation.md#installation---library)

Answer (score 2):

もしかしてマルチポストですか？
https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/issues/439

そもそも現時点のOpenPoseは、VS2017およびCUDA 9.0/9.1環境を正式サポートしていません。*.vcxprojを修正すればコンパイルできるようになるという保証もなく、また仮にコンパイルできたとしても、正常に動作するとはかぎりません。自力で解決するスキルがないのであれば、正式対応を待つべきです。
https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/installation.md

なお、*.vcxprojでは、特定のバージョンのVisual C++コンパイラーが使われるようにプラットフォームツールセットが設定されます。**v141** (VC14.1) はVC2017です。VS2015 (VC2015) でビルドするには、プロジェクトの設定でプラットフォームツールセットを**v140** (VC14.0) に変更する必要があります。MSB8020のエラーは、VS2017向けに構成されたプロジェクトファイルをVS2015でそのまま開いてビルドしようとしたせいで発生したものと推測されます。

Answer (score 0):

もう解決済かもしれませんが、Visual Studio 2017 にインストールできました。
まとめておきましたのでよろしければご参照ください。
https://code.g-nab.net/archives/151